# How To Append Items From An Array to a List Based off User's Input

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function

The program I am attempting to code is similar to a shopping cart. There is a form with two input boxes for the user to input the variables `productCode` and `quantity`. When the button is clicked function `function createList()` is supposed to run and display an output like the picture below. I am trying to append each item to the  `<ul id="list">` every time the button is clicked on and have the `sum` that is sent to `<div id="results>` update each time. I am not sure how to code this for the assignment. I get no syntax errors but nothing displays. Any help and input would be appreciated.

**Example of output**

[image]

**Code Typed So Far**

```
<script>

        //function to create shopping cart
        function createList(){
            
            let products = ["Winter Hat", "Warm Coat", + "Gloves"];
            let prices = [27.50, 160.23, 23.99];
            let sum = 0;
            let li ="";
            let list = document.getElementById("list");
            let productCode = document.getElementById("productCode").value;
            let quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;

            let message = " Product Code or Quantity invalid. Enter values from list above.";

            // for loop to display the appropriate data from appropriate array
            for (let i =0; i < products.length; i++) {
                if (products[i]==productCode) {
                message = products[i] + "(Quantity " +quantity +")" + prices[i];
                sum+= prices[i];

                //creates list element and appends element to id="list"
                li = document.createElement("li");
                li.innerHTML = message;
                list.appendChild(li);
            }
        }   
            // sum is displayed to empty div "results"
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = sum;
    }


    </script>
```

```
<body>
    <h1> Point of Sale System </h1>

    <form id="myForm">
        This is the point of sale program for a store selling winter clothes.

        <ul>
            <li>Product Code 1: “Winter Hat” for $27.50</li>
            <li>Product Code 2: “Warm Coat” for $160.23</li>
            <li>Product Code 3: “Gloves” for $32.99</li>
        </ul>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter the Product Code:</td>
                <!--Input field for productCode-->
                <td><input id="productCode" type="number" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter the Quantity:</td>
                 <!--Input field for quantity-->
                <td><input id="quantity" type="number" value=""></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    
    <input type="button" value="Add this item to purchase order" onclick="createList()">

    <ul id="list"> </ul> 

    <div id="results"></div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: There are many errors which you need to check, but your `createList` function is never being executed. Change `onclick="createList"` to `onclick="createList()"`,

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry just learning how to do it myself. I fixed the error. Only the ````sum```` is displayed but it is 0. What other errors am I making?

Comment: It will be unnecessarily ling discussion here, lets move this discussion to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225187/q-how-to-append-items-from-an-array-to-a-list-based-off-users-input)

Comment: I am sorry. It won't let me chat since my reputation is not high enough

Answer (score 0):

```
let productCode = document.myelement.productCode.value;
let quantity = document.myelement.productCode.value;
```

`document.myelement` does not refer to anything. Instead it would be `document.getElementById("productCode").value`, etc.

Comment: ok thanks I have updated that portion. Nothing gets outputted still. Do you know why?

Comment: Your last error is that you are comparing `products[i]` to `productCode`. That translates to, for example, `"Winter Hat" === 1`, which will evaluate to false. Instead, you want to check for `i === productCode - 1`

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things I would like to point out -

Function brackets are missing for onclick event of add item -

```
<input type="button" value="Add this item to purchase order" onclick="createList()">
```

In code there is no declaration of Product Code array, your input box for product code is number but you are matching that with the values from products array which is of type string

```
if (products[i]==productCode)
```

Try addressing these first and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good problem to use map and reduce function

```js
const purchases = []; // list of products that are purchased so far

function createList() {
  const products = ["Winter Hat", "Warm Coat", +"Gloves"];
  const prices = [27.50, 160.23, 23.99];

  let productCode = document.getElementById("productCode").value;
  let quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;

  const message = " Product Code or Quantity invalid. Enter values from list above.";
  if (productCode < 1 || productCode > 3 || quantity < 1) {
    alert(message);
  }

  purchases.push({
    product: products[productCode - 1],
    quantity: quantity,
    sum: prices[productCode - 1] * quantity
  }); // add the selected product into the purchases list, with its sum


  // once we have all the purchases, we use map function to create
  // the li items as a list and use join to convert it to a string
  // set the string as the innerHTML of ul
  const list = document.getElementById("list");
  list.innerHTML = purchases.map(p => {
    return "<li>" + p.product + " (Quantity: " + p.quantity + ") Cost: " + p.sum + "</li>";
  }).join("");

  // sum up all the purchases
  document.getElementById("results").innerText = purchases.reduce((a, c) => {
    return a + c.sum;
  }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how you used the functions map and push?

Comment: @GatorGat, I have added some docs to the code.